# Using os.path.join in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to reduce/shorten this part quite a lot. If you see that a method can be reduced or even erased please do not hesitate to suggest that. Any answer that rescue the code would be great.

```
(photos, identification, testers, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)

# Get the folders containing the training data
for (subdirectorys, directorys, files) in os.walk(dir):

    # Loop through each folder named after the subject in the photos
    for subdirectory in directorys:
        testers[id] = subdirectory
        subpath = os.path.join(dir, subdirectory)

        # Loop through each photo in the folder
        for file_name in os.listdir(subpath):

            # Skip non-image formates
            f_name, f_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
            if(f_extension.lower() not in
                    ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.pgm']):
                print("Skipping "+file_name+", wrong type given for the file")
                continue
            path = subpath + '/' + file_name
            lable = id

            # Add to training data
            photos.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            identification.append(int(lable))
        id += 1
(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)

# Create a Numpy array from the two lists above
(photos, identification) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [photos, identification]]
```

Comment: Please post working code on Code Review. `sub-directory` is not a valid variable name, please ensure the rest of the code works too.

Comment: It works well, i just had to change the original variable names in order to paste here, and that was mistakenly written - not _. i updated my post :)

Comment: A small note (not a full review): `directorys` looks really odd to an English-speaker.  The correct spelling of the plural form is `directories` (the same is true for `subdirectorys`, too).

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

```
(photos, identification, testers, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)
```

may become

```
photos, identification, testers, id = [], [], {}, 0
```

as parentheses are superfluous (and even it's recommended not use them).

---

```
for (subdirectorys, directorys, files) in os.walk(dir):
```

may become

```
for __, directorys, __ in os.walk(dir):
```

as the names `subdirectorys` and `files` are never used (not two consecutive underline symbols - `__` - for ignoring their values).

---

Instead of maintaining the value of `id` manually (initializing it to `0` and then increase it by `id += 1`) you may use Pythonic way with help of `enumerate()` function - the very first line of you code will totally omit `id`:

```
photos, identification, testers = [], [], {}
```

and your `for` loop

```
    for subdirectory in directorys:
```

becomes

```
    for id, subdirectory in enumerate(directorys):
```

---

Two notes about your `if` statement

```
        if(f_extension.lower() not in
                ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.pgm']):
```

1. Python is not C/C++/Java, so outermost parentheses are superfluous.
2. Your may prepare your list of extensions in advance

   ```
       EXTENSIONS = '.png .jpg .jpeg .gif .pgm'.split()       # split() creates a list
   ```

   (nice method for saving some typing, isn't it?), and then use it:

   ```
       if f_extension.lower() not in EXTENSIONS:
   ```

(note the use of uppercase letters for a constant list).

Comment: Isn't `id` a builtin name?

Comment: @LukaszSalitra - The correct term for `id` is a built-in *function*. You are right - `id()` IS a built-in function, so it would be definitely better to choose other name - in spite of the use of the names of built-in functions for other purpose is not forbidden.

Comment: nitpick: you may want to talk about the proper pluralization of `directory`, which is in fact **not** `directorys`